# Custom Checkout Field in Order Page Column | Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have some custom checkout fields I would like to show as columns, I tired it as it is but only seems to work for standard checkout fields like country, state, first name, etc.

Here is the code I used to create a custom checkout field:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice');

    function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice() {

    $chosen = WC()->session->get('radio_chosen');
    $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? WC()->checkout->get_value('radio_choice') : $chosen;
    $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? 'no_option' : $chosen;

    $args = array(
    'type' => 'radio',
    'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
    'options' => array(
    'option_1' => 'Thursday all day (£12.50)',
    'option_2' => 'Thursday AM (£13.50)',
    'option_3' => 'Friday AM (£13.50)',
    ),
    'default' => $chosen
    );

    echo '<div id="checkout-radio">';
    echo '<h3>Please Select Delivery Day</h3>';
    echo '<p>"Our cut off point is 10am on Monday for orders to be received the same week. If you are placing your order later than this we will schedule your delivery for the following week."</p>';
    woocommerce_form_field( 'radio_choice', $args, $chosen );
    echo '</div>';

    }

    // Part 2 
    // Add Fee and Calculate Total
    // Based on session's "radio_chosen"

    #2 Calculate New Total

    add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_fee', 20, 1 );

    function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_fee( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    $radio = WC()->session->get( 'radio_chosen' );
    $fee = 12.5;
    $deliveryDay = "Normal";
    if ( "option_1" == $radio ) {
    $fee = 12.5;
    $deliveryDay = "Thursday all day";
    } elseif ( "option_2" == $radio ) {
    $fee = 13.5;
    $deliveryDay = "Thursday AM";
    } elseif ( "option_3" == $radio ) {
    $fee = 13.5;
    $deliveryDay = "Friday AM";
    }

    $cart->add_fee( __('Shipping ('. $deliveryDay. ')', 'woocommerce'), $fee );

    }
```